# Автозапуск скрипта python в raspibian на raspberry pi 2

Tags: linux, python-3.x, автозапуск

С недавнего времени мне понадобилось запускать `python скрипт` при старте `raspberry`, проверяющий сообщения в `vk.com` в бесконечном цикле.

Скрипт не работает при записи его ни в `crontab`, ни в `/etc/rc.local`.
Танцы с бубном и `update-c.d` тоже не принесли результат.
Запускается он только если прописать его в `.bashrc`.
*(Везде писал абсолютные пути)*

Скрипт на `Python3`.
Модуль работы с vk.com: `vk_api`.

в crontab -e
@reboot python3 /home/pi/bot/Start.py &> /dev/null

в /etc/rc.local  python3 /home/pi/bot/Start.py &

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as det:
        print(R + "\n Error: " + str(det) + G)
```

(R и G - цвет в терминале)

Comment: покажите что пишете в crontab, выводятся ли какие-нибудь ошибки. Пишете логи из скрипта? Может приведете кусок кода в котором думаете могут быть ошибки

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root - первое что нагуглилось по @reboot, может в нем проблема

Comment: код в вопрос допишите , так не прочитать

Comment: путь лучше указывать абсолютный, а не относительный: `/каталог`, а не `каталог`.

Comment: ошибся в пути, было исправлено

Comment: так напишите, что именно «не так». запускается ли этот скрип? работает ли этот скрипт? если не работает,  то почему именно не работает?

Comment: скрипт запускается. если запускать его как ./Start.py или python3 Start.py, а в автозагрузке его нет, логов нет. эту проблему я пытаюсь и решить

Comment: так с какими проблемами вы столкнулись? не знаете, как, например, создать с помощью python файл, чтобы было понятно, запускался ли ваш скрипт вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил я это достаточно необычно. 
Все дело было в том, что vk_api по каким-то своим причинам не могла залогинить мой акк.
Поэтому в начале программы мне пришлось пинговать сервер из сети, чтобы удостовериться в работоспособности Интернета в данный момент

```
def ping(host='google.com'):
    return os.system('ping -c 1 ' + host) == 0
while not ping()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: обычно такие проблемы решаются указанием зависимости на сетевой (и другие) сервисы, чтобы ваша задаче не запускалась до того как сеть, домашняя директория и другие нужные ресурсы  станут доступны http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/